# Why input class not found in laravel 5.2?

Tags: class, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel 5.2.3, I have tried in controller, and is giving input class not found error.

```
public static function(){
    $user = new \App\User;
    $user->username = Input::get('username');
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Input;

At top of your controller and it should solve the error you have.